# Two dice thrown and its distribution does not correspond with probabilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, distribution, dice

In the board game Catan, you throw 2 six-sided dice every turn, the possible results go from 2 to 12 and the distribution of the sum should be something like this in 100,000 throws:

```
***CATAN DICE***

2 *****5998

3 ********8170

4 ********8170

5 **********10299

6 ************12283

7 **************14341

8 ************12331

9 **********10149

10 ********8090

11 ******6033

12 ****4068
```

However I only get this result when the dice is seven-sided from 0 to 6 using `randint(0, 6)`.
When I use `randint(1,6)` the distribution is the following:

```
***CATAN DICE***

2 **2771

3 *****5560

4 *****5560

5 ********8410

6 ***********11088

7 **************14132

8 ****************16491

9 *************13768

10 ***********11163

11 ********8220

12 *****5616
```

Which is wrong, the 8 is not more likely to occur in a pair of six sided dice.
¿Is something wrong in my code?, ¿could it be related to the way `randint()` works?

This is my code:

```
from random import randint

print("***CATAN DICE***")

normal = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(0, 100000):
    a=randint(0, 6)
    b=randint(0, 6)
    throw = a+b
    if throw == 2:
        normal[0]+=1        
    if throw == 3:
        normal[1]+=1
    if throw == 3:
        normal[2]+=1
    if throw == 4:
        normal[3]+=1
    if throw == 5:
        normal[4]+=1
    if throw == 6:
        normal[5]+=1
    if throw == 7:
        normal[6]+=1
    if throw == 8:
        normal[7]+=1
    if throw == 9:
        normal[8]+=1
    if throw == 10:
        normal[9]+=1
    if throw == 11:
        normal[10]+=1
i=0
j=0
for i in range(len(normal)):
    print(i+2, end = " ")
    for j in range(int(normal[i]/1000)):
        print("*",end="")
    print(f"{normal[i]}\n")
```

Comment: first you should have randint(1,6) and not randint(0,6)

Comment: If you are using numpy, you could do: `np.unique(np.random.randint(1, 7, [100000, 2]).sum(1), return_counts = True)`

Comment: I tried both: randint(1,6) and randint (0,6) but when I use 1,6 I get the 8 more often which is wrong.

Comment: Your problem is in your `if` statements. You have two occurrences of  `if throw == 3:`. Your double `5560` is a hint to this.

Comment: There is no normal distribution here.  The sum of two discrete uniforms has a discrete triangle distribution.

Comment: @Axe319 a perfect illustration of the dangers of using copy/paste to duplicate repetitive code.  I remember seeing a utility that could find errors like that automatically, but I can't remember what it was.

Comment: Your expected sums are off, they should look more like: 2778, 5556, 8333, 11111, 13889, 16667, 13889, 11111, 8333, 5556, 2778.

Answer (score 2):

You made your code more complex than it need be, and in the process introduced some bugs.  I eliminated the chain of `if` statements by calculating the index to be updated directly from the outcome `throw`.  I eliminated looping to get the stars one-by-one, used rounding rather than integer truncation (floor) to get the number of stars, and right-justified the value of the sum.  I also grouped the code into initialization, generation, and output stages to make it easy to read and easy to alter the number of trials being run.  Without further ado, the code:

```python
from random import randint

# initialize
n = 100000
count = [0 for _ in range(11)]  # less prone to a manual miscount error

# generate : no need for if's, calculate index directly from throw outcome
for i in range(n):
    throw = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)
    count[throw - 2] += 1

# output
print("***CATAN DICE***\n")

for i in range(len(count)):
    stars = "" + "*" * round(count[i] / (n // 100))
    print(f"{i + 2 :>2} " + stars + f"{count[i]}")
```

which produces output such as:

```text
***CATAN DICE***

 2 ***2741
 3 ******5637
 4 ********8210
 5 ***********11099
 6 **************14068
 7 *****************16659
 8 **************13821
 9 ***********11074
10 ********8365
11 ******5500
12 ***2826
```

It's very easy to modify this if you want die outcomes from 0 to 6 rather than from 1 to 6.

---

Finally, just for fun, here's a more generalized implementation so you can play around with number of dice and ranges on the dice.

```python
from random import randint

# initialize
n = 100000      # trials
num_dice = 2    # number of dice

# low and high values for a die
die_lo = 1
die_hi = 6

min_outcome = num_dice * die_lo
num_outcomes = num_dice * die_hi - min_outcome + 1

# generate : no need for if's, calculate index directly from throw outcome
count = [0 for _ in range(num_outcomes)]
for i in range(n):
    throw = sum(randint(die_lo, die_hi) for _ in range(num_dice))
    count[throw - min_outcome] += 1

# output
print("***CATAN DICE***\n")

for i in range(num_outcomes):
    stars = "" + "*" * round(count[i] / (n // 100))
    print(f"{i + min_outcome :>3} " + stars + f"{count[i]}")
```

I think this illustrates the benefit of not hardwiring a chain of `if` statements.